# How to prevent drawer close gesture from stealing events

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I have a modal screen with swipe-to-reveal sections. I'd like to move it to a drawer, but the drawer close action steals all the gestures. Is there a way to prevent this?

A crude way could be to have `disableCloseGesture`. Ideally, it would only respond to touches starting at the opposite edge to the side of the drawer.